# Return a Promise from Redux Observable

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but a common pattern I use with redux-thunk is to return a promise so I can perform some additional actions in the container object when something completes or fails.

---

Using Thunk as an example:

Action Creator:

```
const action = ({ data }) => (dispatch) => 
    fetch(`some http url`)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
             return response.json();
        }

        return Promise.reject(response);
    })
```

Somewhere in the connected component:

```
this.props.action("Some Data")
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(error => console.error("ERROR"));
```

---

Is there a clean way of doing something similar in Redux-Observable/Rxjs? Basically returning a promise from an action, calling an epic, that returns resolve or reject once the observable is complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, I try to shy people away from these patterns when using things like redux-observable/redux-saga. Instead, if you're waiting for an action you dispatched to update the store's state, rely on that state update itself or some sort of transactional metadata your reducers store in the state about it. e.g. `{ transactions: { "123": { isPending: true, error: null } }`

However, if you *really* do want to do it, you can write (or use an existing) middleware that returns a Promise from `dispatch` that will resolve when some other specified action has been dispatched (presumably by your epics). [redux-wait-for-action](https://github.com/Chion82/redux-wait-for-action) is one example (not a recommendation, though cause I haven't used any)

Keep in mind that Promises are not normally cancellable, so you could accidentally create a situation where a component starts waiting for an action, the user leaves that page and the component is unmounted, and you're still waiting for that other action--which can cause weirdness later, like if they come back to that page, etc.

---

If you're waiting to *chain* side effects, that belongs in your epics. Kick off a single action that an epic listens for, makes the side effect, then it emits another action to signal completion. Another epic listens for that completion action and then begins the other side effect, etc. You could put them all in a single monolithic epic, if you want, but I find the separation easier for testing and reuse.

Comment: Might be answering my own question, but what about cases when there is a non-renderable side effect from an action? Using the above example, let's say we want to call a component's `this.someInternalFunc()` after `isPending` switches from true to false (fetching completes from epic). We then have to leverage a lifecycle hook like `componentWillReceiveProps()`, and check if our props from the reducer changed. (?)

Comment: There are no rules per say, but it sounds like logic that belongs in your epics. Except for generic components which maintain private, internal state, your other components should not contain business logic like that. They render DOM, and in response to UI events dispatch actions and then rerender according to the store's state and their props--that's it.

Comment: If you want to perform one side effect, then after it's done do another, that's ripe stuff for epics. Dispatch a single action to kick the chain of side effects that will be handled in one or more epics.