# How to set state the data in componentDidMount method from the epic redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am new to redux-observable. I have an epic function which request an api call and emmit a new success action. What is the clean way to get the data in my react view? In my componentDidmount method I call the getUsers redux action. I wanted to set the state in componentDidmount but It will run only once and will not wait the promise epic.

```js
const getUsersEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(GET_USERS)
        .mergeMap( action =>
            Observable.fromPromise(
                axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: API_USERS,
                    headers : getHeaders().toObject()
                })
            )
        )
        .flatMap((response) => {
            if(response.status == 200) {
                return [{
                    type: GET_USERS_SUCCESS,
                    data: response.data,
                    status: response.status
                }]
            }
            else {
                return [{
                    type: GET_USERS_ERROR,
                    message: 'error',
                    status: response.status
                }]
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            // console.log('error', error)
            return setResponseError(error,  GET_USERS_ERROR);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dispatch an action in `componentDidMount()` that is intercepted by `redux-observable` and used to make ajax call. As a result, you get `GET_USERS_SUCCESS` or `GET_USERS_ERROR` action dispatched to redux at some point in the future. Generally, there is no way to await these actions in components. And I think it's a good limitation because this restricts async handling in the component which can in many ways introduce bugs.

What you need to do is set default state in reducer which is later updated by request response and pass it down as a props to your component.

Also, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380877/4443323) by one of the redux-observable authors.

By the way is there any reason why you Axios instead `AjaxObservable`

Comment: Thanks setting a default state in my reducer solves the problem. About the axios, Im kinda new to reactive programming so I havent actually explored rxjs available methods.